# Exclude tpl files in multisite theme

Tags: theming, multi-sites

I'm working in a multisite, the theme had `page--front.tpl.php` file for the main site, but I want to exclude this file in the other sites.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its trickier to 'remove' the template on sites you don't want it on because Drupal will always recognize the file format as a valid template and add it to [theme suggestions](https://drupal.org/node/1089656). An easier option would be to affirmatively add it using a custom module only on the sites you want it on. For example, following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305114/drupal-7-how-to-load-a-template-file-from-a-module), here's how you would register a particular template file only on the subsites you want by just selectively enabling the module where you need it:

```
/*
 * Implementation of hook_theme().
 */
function YOUR_SUBSITE_MODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
  return array(
    'YOUR_SUBSITE' => array(
      'variables' => array('content' => NULL),
      'file' => 'page--front', // place your file in 'theme' folder of you module folder
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'YOUR_SUBSITE_MODULE') .'/theme'
    )
  );
}

function YOUR_SUBSITE_MODULE_page(){

  // some code to generate $content variable

  return theme('YOUR_SUBSITE', $content); // use $content variable in moon.tpl.php template
}
```